# Accessing the State of a Functional Component with React Hooks when Testing with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-hooks

I was wondering how to test a state change of functional components with the `useState` hook with Enzyme. Usually the test would be something along the lines of `expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual(expectedState)` but I get the error:

```
ReactWrapper::state() can only be called on class components
```

I know that Hooks are still in the alpha stage and things like `shallow` still don't work but I was wondering is there a way to this yet?

Comment: Here's one perspective: https://blog.kentcdodds.com/react-hooks-whats-going-to-happen-to-my-tests-df4c2b4d67b7

Comment: Have you considered testing your React components without accessing its state? When it comes to testing, I always try to test behavior instead of implementation. It keeps my tests isolated from the implementation logic, but still enforcing the expected behavior. When you check the values of the component state, you are testing the implementation of the component. You should be able to, given a set of props you pass to your component, when you interact with it, then you should see something different being rendered, or some other kind of perceived side effect, like an API call.

Answer (score 6):

You should avoid testing implementation details. Instead, test if the behavior of the component, when triggering an action which would update your state, acts as you would expect.

Comment: I really don't see how this is an acceptable way of programming unit tests. Some behavior might be simple enough, but dealing with complex frontend, this approach might get complicated quickly. For example, when you have drag and drop functionality implemented that relies on one or multiple libraries, it might be hard to implement a certain behavior here.

Comment: @yemerra I agree with you. It seems that the same question gets asked over and over and people keep repeating whatever someone said, in a blog post. In the end, this doesn't answer the question. A better answer would be to say: "you can't test the state of a function component".

Comment: @ross-u is this still the case? Can we still not unit test the useState() react hook?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not control a component state. Unit tests should be control inputs and outputs.

Like this:

> Give status prop true to FormComponent expect **.send-user-data** button exist.

If you check the Enyzme source code [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/packages/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js#L724). You can see instance and class type check. Functional components nodeTypes not equal to class and not have instance.

You can use https://github.com/etiennedi/enzyme-wait for wait for async elements.

Your test can be like this.

> Simulate click event **.send-user-data** button wait(its. setTimeout, promise or xhr) and expect returned
>   user.